# How to get data from web service in servlet

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I need to get the data passed from web service to my servlet. This is the code in my web service:

```
if (generatedKey > 0L) {
            System.out.println("Response.ok(generatedKey, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();");
            URI uri = info.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path("createECommerceTransactionRecord?generatedKey=" + generatedKey).build();
            return Response.created(uri).build();
        }
```

How do I get the URI in my servlet?